# How to preserve holes when combining contours into polygons via R?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, r-raster

Part of the workflow for my project requires creating contours from a raster. I am able to generate the contours using `raster::rasterToContour` and can convert to a polygon using the `sf` package in R, but am having some trouble getting the desired outcome.

Here is a scaled-down example of what I am currently doing:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

raster <- raster(matrix(c(rep(0,5),
                          0,1,1,1,0,
                          0,1,0,1,0,
                          0,1,1,1,0,
                          rep(0,5)), nrow = 5, ncol = 5))
plot(raster)

contour <- rasterToContour(raster, level = 0.5)
plot(contour, add = TRUE)

sf <- st_as_sf(contour) %>% st_polygonize()
plot(sf, col = "gray50", border = "black")
```

The initial [contour plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytBWb.png) seems to work appropriately for what I need. However, I can't seem to figure out how to avoid the central region becoming filled, as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzmGM.png). I would like the central portion to become a hole in the larger polygon so that it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VHFw.png). I'm sure I can achieve this by pulling the polygons into GIS software, but it would be helpful to do so within R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `st_cast("POLYGON")` instead of `st_polygonize()`:

```r
library(raster)
library(stars)
library(sf)

m <- matrix(c(rep(0,5),
              0,1,1,1,0,
              0,1,0,1,0,
              0,1,1,1,0,
              rep(0,5)), nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

contour_1 <- 
  raster(m) |>
  rasterToContour(level = 0.5) |>
  st_as_sf() |> 
  st_cast("POLYGON")
contour_1
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.2 ymin: 0.2 xmax: 0.8 ymax: 0.8
#> CRS:           NA
#>     level                       geometry
#> C_1   0.5 POLYGON ((0.3 0.2, 0.2 0.3,...
plot(contour_1)
```

[image]

Or perhaps `stars` and `stars::st_contour()`:

```r
contour_2 <- 
  st_as_stars(m) |> 
  st_contour()
contour_2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 5 ymax: 5
#> CRS:           NA
#>           A1  Min Max                       geometry
#> 1 [-0.5,0.5) -0.5 0.5 MULTIPOLYGON (((4.5 5, 5 5,...
#> 2  [0.5,1.5)  0.5 1.5 MULTIPOLYGON (((4.000001 3....
plot(contour_2[,"A1"], key.pos = NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>